# How to initialize member in abstract class with std::function in which pure virtual member is called?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Here is the problem:

I have a class called `Object`, whose constructor accepts a `std::function` like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Object {
 public:
  Object(std::function<void(int param)> f) : func(f) {}
  ~Object() { func(0); }
 private:
  std::function<void(int param)> func;
};
```

Then an abstract base class and several derived classes like this:

```
class AbstractBase {
 public:
  AbstractBase() {
    // How to initialize object.
  }
  virtual std::string toString() const = 0;

 private:
  Object object;
};

class Derived1 : public AbstractBase {
 public:
  std::string toString() const override { return "Derived1"; }
}

class Derived2 : public AbstractBase {
 public:
  std::string toString() const override { return "Derived2"; }
}
```

I am trying to initialize the `object` in `AbstractBase` like this:

```
AbstractBase()
    : object([this](int param) {
        // do something
        std::cout << toString() << std::endl;
        // do something
      }) {}
```

It compiles successfully, but raises "pure virtual method called" when `AbstractBase` is deleted. So how can I initialize `object` in the `AbstractBase` and make sure `toString` from derived class is called in the `std::function`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Are you trying to use the `object`'s function on `this` in `~AbstractBase()`?

Comment: Think about when the `AbstractBase` destructor runs.

Comment: Updated the question. The desired behavior is that `Object` is used to capture some information from `Derived1` and `Derived2` and when `Object` is destructed, the collected information is saved (or in this case print to stdout).

Comment: At the point of the call, your object is no longer a `Derived2`. Therefore the `Derived2::toString()` isn't called. The obvious solution is to not call virtual functions inside constructors or destructors (which is a sensible advice not only in C++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is order of destructors calls. 
Here is a simple example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Object {
 public:
  Object(){ cout<<"O\n"; }
 ~Object() { cout<<"~O\n"; }
};

class AbstractBase {
 public:
  AbstractBase(){ cout<<"A\n"; }
 ~AbstractBase() { cout<<"~A\n"; }

 private:
  Object object;
};

class Derived1 : public AbstractBase {
 public:
 Derived1() : AbstractBase()
 { cout<<"1\n"; }
 ~Derived1() { cout<<"~1\n"; }
};

class Derived2 : public AbstractBase {
 public:
 Derived2() : AbstractBase()
 { cout<<"2\n"; }
 ~Derived2() { cout<<"~2\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
O
A
1
O
A
2
~2
~A
~O
~1
~A
~O
```

As you can see Objects destructors are called after Derived* destructors, so, in your code, Object is trying to call already destructed Derived* method.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard forbids calling a pure virtual method from either a constructor or a destructor.

If you were to directly call `toString()` from `~AbstractBase()` you would almost certainly get a compiler error.

Your use of a lambda is basically "sneaking" the disallowed behaviour past the compiler.

Instead, you need to move the responsibility up to `Derived` - consider something like this:

```
struct Object {
     Object(decltype(func) f) : func(f) {};
     ~Object() { func(); }
   private:
     std::function<void()> func; //removed param since it's unused in your example
};

struct AbstractBase {
    A() = delete;
  protected:
    A(Object&& o) : obj(o) {} //we'll be using an rvalue in this example, be mindful of object lifetime in other usages
  private:
    Object& o;
};

struct Derived : AbstractBase {
    Derived() : AbstractBase(Object{[this]() { writestr(); }}) {}
  private:
    void writestr() { std::cout << "yes"; }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    return 0;
}
```